# What is the value of an infinite odds ratios with non-signification p-value?

Tags: interpretation, odds-ratio, fishers-exact-test

I have a contingency table as follows:

```
        Tumour
Healthy Pos Neg
    Pos   4   0
    Neg   2   3
```

I ran Fisher's exact test to get the odds ratio (using R) and I got:

```
    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  meld
p-value = 0.1667
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3779205       Inf
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
       Inf
```

How shall I interpret the result? An infinite OR sounds already bad to me, but coupled with a non-significant p-value (inclusion of 1 in the CI), I'd say there is no difference between the classes. Am I right?

Thank you

Comment: The `Inf` does not designate an infinite odds ratio--it's simply a way of stating there is no upper confidence limit.  In other words, there is 95% confidence that the odds ratio exceeds 0.3779.  No special reinterpretation is required.

Comment: OK, so how shall I report it? OR=∞ (0.378-∞), p-val = 0.167? Thank you

Comment: I would report it as "there aren't enough data either to estimate or detect a difference ($p=1/6$)."